# Design Report Criteria in the Jasper Report it-self

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am new to Jasper Server. I installed and able to create reports and calling them by using visualize js by passing input criteria from custom web based application.

But I want to create that Report criteria in the report level. So that i can render directly in my custom web application.

Could anyboby tell me how can do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could anybody help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to render inputcontrol:

I will refer to:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-visualizejs-guide/v640/api-reference-inputcontrols

```
<div id="inputContainer"></div>

    visualize({
        auth: { ...
        }
    }, function (v) {
        var inputControls = v.inputControls({
            resource: "/public/Samples/Reports/Cascading_Report_2_Updated",
            container: "#inputContainer",
            error: function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });


    });
```